# Finding the Average, minimum, maximum, and range

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java and am stopped by my assignment to write a code which finds the average, minimum, maximum, and range of an input. This is all of my code and it is not finished. The average comes out fine but the minimum and max I have written don't even read. Can anyone help me connect the min and max to my inputs?

```
package averages;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Averages {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //initialize variables
    double sum =0;
    int count = 0;
    double grade =0;
    //initialize scanner and input
    System.out.print("Enter Grades, enter -1 to end the set:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    //Process data until sentinel is entered
    while (grade != -1)
    {
        grade = in.nextDouble();
        if (grade != -1)
        {
            sum = sum + grade;
            count++;
        }
    }
   // Finding the average
    if(count > 0)
    {
        double average = sum/ count;
        System.out.println("Grade Average: "+average);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No Data");
    }
    //Finding largest grade
    double largest = in.nextDouble();
    while(in.hasNextDouble())
    {
        double input = in.nextDouble();
        if(input > largest)
        {
            largest = input;
        }
        System.out.println(largest);
    //Finding smallest grade    
    double smallest = in.nextDouble();
    while (in.hasNextDouble())
    {
        double input1 = in.nextDouble();
        if(input1 < smallest)
        {
            smallest = input;

        }
        System.out.println(smallest);
    }}}}
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for [nextDouble()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    //initialize variables
    double sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double grade = 0;
    double largest = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    double smallest = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    //initialize scanner and input
    System.out.print("Enter Grades, enter -1 to end the set:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Process data until sentinel is entered
    while (grade != -1) {
        grade = in.nextDouble();
        if (grade != -1) {
            sum = sum + grade;
            if (grade > largest) {
                largest = grade;
            }
            if (grade < smallest) {
                smallest = grade;
            }

            count++;
        }
    }
    // Finding the average
    if (count > 0) {
        double average = sum / count;
        System.out.println("Grade Average: " + average);
        System.out.println("Max Grade: " + largest);
        System.out.println("Min Grade: " + smallest);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No Data");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not answer homework questions, only guide the questioner. If the poster cannot figure it out on  his own and gets his degree through stackoverflow, it will be worthless, he will not be able to pass any technical interviews.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. The other codes supplied were helpful but we havnt reached arrays yet in my java class so this made the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it collects all input doubles, and work with them:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Averages {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //initialize variables
    double sum =0;
    double grade =0;
    double min = 0;
    double max = 0;
    //initialize scanner and input
    System.out.print("Enter Grades, enter -1 to end the set:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    //Process data until sentinel is entered
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

    while (grade != -1)
    {
        grade = in.nextDouble();
        if (grade != -1)
        {
            list.add(grade);
        }
    }
    // Finding the average
    if(!list.isEmpty())
    {
        max = list.get(0);
        min = list.get(0);
        for(double i : list){
            if(i>max) max = i;
            if(i<min) min = i;
            sum += i;
        }
        System.out.println("Avarage:"+sum/list.size());
        System.out.println("Max:"+max);
        System.out.println("Min"+min);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No Data");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should not answer homework questions, only guide the questioner. If the poster cannot figure it out on  his own and gets his degree through stackoverflow, it will be worthless, he will not be able to pass any technical interviews.

Comment: @TonyBenBrahim Yes, i think you get the point. Thank you for 'reprimand'. I will pay more attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution similar to that of @m.cekiera.  I used a list but created separate methods

```
public static double average(List<Double> datas) {
    double sum = 0.0D;
    for (double d:datas) {
        sum += d;
    }
    return sum/datas.size();
}

public static double min(List<Double> datas) {
    double min = datas.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < datas.size(); i++) {
        if (datas.get(i) < min) {
            min = datas.get(i);
        }
    }

    return min;
}

public static double max(List<Double> datas) {
    double max = datas.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < datas.size(); i++) {
        if (datas.get(i) > max) {
            max = datas.get(i);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

And then the main method is simplified

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //initialize variables
    double sum =0;
    int count = 0;
    double grade =0;
    //initialize scanner and input
    System.out.print("Enter Grades, enter -1 to end the set:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    List<Double> datas = new ArrayList<Double>();
    // Collect all the datas and use sentinel to mark the end
    //Process data until sentinel is entered
    while (grade != -1)
    {
        grade = in.nextDouble();
        if (grade != -1)
        {
            datas.add(grade);
           // sum = sum + grade;
           // count++;
        }
    }
   // Finding the average, the min and the max
    if(datas.size() > 0)
    {
        double average = sum/ datas.size();
        double min = min(datas);
        double max = max(datas);
        average = average(datas);
        System.out.println("Grade Average: "+average);
        System.out.println("Min: " + min);
        System.out.println("Max: " + max);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No Data");
    }



}
```

Comment: You should not answer homework questions, only guide the questioner. If the poster cannot figure it out on  his own and gets his degree through stackoverflow, it will be worthless, he will not be able to pass any technical interviews.

Comment: @Tony BenBrahim, that's right. But it seemed to me that the OP did some effort. I will be cautious about this next time. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your code, even though I had most of the code it always helps to read code from an experienced programmer!